# React json array not rendered

Tags: reactjs

I have my myArray filled from post request. I want to fill the table with these values dynamically however it renders nothing.

```
class Reports extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      
      id:"",
      myArray: [],
}
}

componentDidMount(e) {
    console.log("fetching")
    fetch('/getMetaReport', {
      method: 'post',
      headers: {'Content-Type':'application/json', 'Accept': 'application/json'},
      body: JSON.stringify({id: 7}),
    }).then(res => res.json()).catch(error => {
      console.error('Error:', error);
  })
  .then(response => {
      console.log(response);
      this.state.myArray.push(response);
      console.log(this.state.myArray)
      
  }) 
  }
```

I can print the values in the console but I can't fill the table with them.

```
    
    return (
      <div className={s.root}>
        <h2 className="page-title" style={{color: "black"}}>
          Reports
        </h2>
        
<table>
                <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>ID</th>
                    <th>Title</th>
                    <th>Date</th>
                </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    {
                        this.state.myArray.map((item) => (
                            <tr key={item.id}>
                                <td>{item.id}</td>
                                <td>{item.title}</td>
                                <td>{item.date}</td>
                                <td/>
                            </tr>
                        ))
                    }
                </tbody>
            </table>
        
      </div>
    )
  }
```

Why does it render nothing and how can I fill my table with the values from the JSON array dynamically? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You are not trigger a rerender. Try this

`this.setState({'myArray': [...this.state.myArray, response]})`

Comment: I added this in my ComponentDidMount but now it gives "Warning: Each child in a list should have a unique "key" prop." error

Comment: It is reffering to the elements in your `return` block. I'm a bit rusty but this either means you have multiple elements with the same `item.id` (from `<tr key={item.id}>`) or it wants each `<td>` to have it's own key. Try something like 

`<td key={\`id-${item.id}\`}/>`
Then do something similar for each `<td>`

Answer (score 0):

Although what Cody E mentioned is correct, if you want to 'push' new items into an existing array (and not replace the entire array), the best way is by using the prevState param. Otherwise you may find side effects.

```
this.setState((prevState) => {
  return { myArray: [...prevState.myArray, ...response] }
})
```

More here: https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html

Comment: After I add this, I got many errors but when I do what Cody E said, it doesn't render anything :(

Comment: Could you elaborate in your errors? I'm positive this is the right way of writing it. You can also create a Sandbox to share. I would double check the response object as may be the issue here.

Comment: Also, for you case scenario you don't need to use the previous state, try this:
this.setState({ myArray: [...response]})

Comment: I added this.setState({ myArray: [...response]}) and it gives this error: Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): Invalid attempt to spread non-iterable instance

Comment: Looks like response is not what you think it is. Must not be at array as such.

Comment: {1: {…}, 2: {…}, 3: {…},
1: {date: "20.04.2021", id: 1, title: "dene"}
2: {date: "20.04.2021", id: 2, title: "deneme"}
3: {date: "21.04.2021", id: 3, title: "beyza"}   my response looks like this in console, maybe it can be helpful

Comment: Yep, that's an object, not an array.
this.setState({ myArray: {...response} }) will do the job, but still, is a javascritp object, not array.

Comment: thanks for your comments, I will try to fix this: Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): Invalid attempt to spread non-iterable instance

Comment: No worries, good luck with that. 99% sure the problem is the response.Try "myArray: response". just in case. cheers